JSON Schema: anyOf and additionalProperties: false failing validation
I have the following schema where I am using a choice of one of two subschemas for the payload.
{
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "XXXTrades": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "XXX Trades",
      "properties": {
        "instrumentTypes": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "minItems": 1
        }
      },
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "books": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "minItems": 1
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "books"
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "tradeLegIds": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "minItems": 1
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "tradeLegIds"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "YYYYTrades": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "YYYY Trades",
      "properties": {
        "sourceType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "YYYY"
          ]
        },
        "folioInstrumentFilter": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "title": "YYYY Folios",
          "properties": {
            "folios": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "minItems": 1
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "folios"
          ]
        },
        {
          "title": "YYYY Trade Ids",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "YYYYTradeIds": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            },
            "minItems": 1
          },
          "required": [
            "YYYYTradeIds"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "required": [
        "sourceType"
      ],
      "allOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "folioInstrumentFilter": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "folioInstrumentFilter"
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "required": [
              "folios"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/YYYYTrades"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/XXXTrades"
    }
  ]
}

However the following payload fails to validate
{
  "YYYYTradeIds": [
    1
  ],
  "sourceType": "YYYY"
}

with the following validation error
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "instancePath": "",
      "schemaPath": "#/definitions/YYYYTrades/additionalProperties",
      "keyword": "additionalProperties",
      "params": {
        "additionalProperty": "YYYYTradeIds"
      },
      "message": "must NOT have additional properties",
      ...
...
..
    {
      "instancePath": "",
      "schemaPath": "#/definitions/XXXTrades/oneOf",
      "keyword": "oneOf",
      "params": {
        "passingSchemas": null
      },
      "message": "must match exactly one schema in oneOf",
      ...
...
  ]
}

It seems that the validator AJV8 is failing to determine which of the sub schemas to use when validating the payload. Is there any mechanism to force the parser/validator to apply the correct sub schema?
I tried inlining the schema instead of using definitions, adding conditions on sourceType but it didn't work.. I have been looking for solutions online for a couple of days.

You have a common mistake in your schema.  additionalProperties: false and composition keywords such as anyOf and oneOf don't play nice together in earlier versions of JSON Schema.  I assume you are using draft-07, which is the default AJV 8 implementation.
To make this behavior work correctly, you need to define the keywords in the subschemas at the root, using an empty schema {} or true is sufficient.
With if, then, typically a schema constraint should be used more than just the type if you have already defined the type elsewhere. Otherwise, it's a lot of extra processing and syntax for the use case you have, which is to enforce a specific property if another property exists. This can be done with dependencies.
The updates I've made to your schema,

define JSON Schema version, this is important for the keyword behavior
define subschema keywords at the root with true
replace allOf>if>then constraint with dependencies
misplaced minItems in YYYYTradeIds subschema

{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "XXXTrades": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "XXX Trades",
      "properties": {
        "instrumentTypes": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "minItems": 1
        },
        "books": true,
        "tradeLegIds": true
      },
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "books": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "minItems": 1
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "books"
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "tradeLegIds": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "minItems": 1
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "tradeLegIds"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "YYYYTrades": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "YYYY Trades",
      "properties": {
        "sourceType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "YYYY"
          ]
        },
        "folioInstrumentFilter": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "folios": true,
        "YYYYTradeIds": true
      },
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "title": "YYYY Folios",
          "properties": {
            "folios": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "minItems": 1
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "folios"
          ]
        },
        {
          "title": "YYYY Trade Ids",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "YYYYTradeIds": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "minItems": 1
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "YYYYTradeIds"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "required": [
        "sourceType"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "folioInstrumentFilter": [
          "folios"
        ]
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/YYYYTrades"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/XXXTrades"
    }
  ]
}


If you're interested and willing to move to a newer JSON Schema draft, you can avoid the additionalProperties issue and duplicate definitions at the root of the schema with the use of a newer keyword, unevaluatedProperties.  This keyword can see into  a subschema defined in a composition (allOf, oneOf, anyOf) keyword, unlike additionalProperties.
A few other changes required for Draft 2020-12

$schema requires the proper version
definitions is updated to $defs
additionalProperties is updated to unevaluatedProperties
dependencies is updated to dependentRequired
duplicate keyword definitions at the root of the schema are no longer required
Ajv must import a different module to validate Draft 2020-12. This module is included in the common Ajv package.

const Ajv = require('ajv/dist/2020');
const ajv = new Ajv({ strict: false });

let instance = // your json data instance
let schema = // your json schema

try {
    const validate = ajv.compile(schema)

    const valid = validate(instance)

    console.log(results = { valid: valid, error: validate.errors })
} catch ({ message }) {
    console.error(message)
}

{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "$defs": {
    "XXXTrades": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "XXX Trades",
      "properties": {
        "instrumentTypes": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "minItems": 1
        }
      },
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "books": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "minItems": 1
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "books"
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "tradeLegIds": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "minItems": 1
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "tradeLegIds"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "unevaluatedProperties": false
    },
    "YYYYTrades": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "YYYY Trades",
      "properties": {
        "sourceType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "YYYY"
          ]
        },
        "folioInstrumentFilter": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "title": "YYYY Folios",
          "properties": {
            "folios": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "minItems": 1
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "folios"
          ]
        },
        {
          "title": "YYYY Trade Ids",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "YYYYTradeIds": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "minItems": 1
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "YYYYTradeIds"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "required": [
        "sourceType"
      ],
      "dependentRequired": {
        "folioInstrumentFilter": [
          "folios"
        ]
      },
      "unevaluatedProperties": false
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/$defs/YYYYTrades"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "#/$defs/XXXTrades"
    }
  ]
}

